Editing user input in a InputField
I am trying to format the user input in an InputField so that the input is formatted and then displayed back to the user, within the InputField.
InputField[ Dynamic[input],FieldSize->10]

where
If[StringMatchQ[input, NumberString], 
 NumberForm[ToExpression[input], DigitBlock -> 3, 
  NumberSeparator -> " "], "Enter a number"]

Is this possible?

Note: MMA format Integers automatically in your chosen format.
Try this:
input = "Enter a number";
InputField[Dynamic[input], FieldSize -> 10]
Button["Accept", 
 input = NumberForm[input, 20, DigitBlock -> 3, 
   NumberSeparator -> " "]]


Now enter a number:

Click the button:


Thank you @Daniel . What do you mean by "Chosen Format"? Is there a global setting to change all output's to a desired format, i.e. not scientific notation. I had hoped the inputfield simply had a 'styling' function to achieve this, but if it can be done globally that would be great!
There is probably a similar solution whereby 'on insert of value -> call some function -> function then updates the value with NumberForm', that does not need a button, all working Dynamically.

Global setting under Appearance only allows me change how many digits it displays, not the format, i.e. not scientific notation.

With "Chosen Format" I mean the format specified in NumberForm[...
